# How to fire alert after sql command executed?

Tags: jsp, alert

I need to get alert once I add the product successfuly after executing sql statement

I have try this but there no alert message after adding the product sucessfully

```html
<%@include file="connection.jsp" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% 
         String dbpname = request.getParameter("pname");
         String dbpid = request.getParameter("pid");
         String dbptype = request.getParameter("ptype");
         String dbaddress = request.getParameter("address");
         String dbaddress1 = request.getParameter("address1");
         String dbpquat = request.getParameter("pquat");    
         String dbpcost = request.getParameter("pcost");
         
           PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into PRODUCT  values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,0,0)");
           
           ps.setString(1,dbpname);
           ps.setString(2,dbpid);
           ps.setString(3,dbptype);
           ps.setString(4,dbaddress);
           ps.setString(5,dbaddress1);
           ps.setString(6,dbpquat);
          
           ps.setString(7,dbpcost);
           
          int i=ps.executeUpdate();
          if(i!=0)
          {
           { %>
   <script> alert("added sucessfully");</script>; <%
        
          response.sendRedirect("AddProducts.jsp");}
                        
             %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your alert disappears into nirvana because you redirect immediatly afterwards, so there is never time to show it. You can display the alert in AddProducts .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after this jsp executes the SQL update, it redirects to AddProducts.jsp. That is way the alert never shows into the browse r. You test that with browser http traces. To fix it you can remove response.sendRedirect and do JavaScript redirect ( `window.location = url;` ), after the alert has shown.
replace the code block:
   alert("added sucessfully");; <%

```
      response.sendRedirect("AddProducts.jsp");}

         %>
```

with:

```
<script> 
  alert("added sucessfully");
      window.location = "AddProducts.jsp";  
 </script>
```

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert("added successfully")  ;
            response.sendRedirect("AddProducts.jsp");
            


i have tried this but just alert is firing and page is not redirecting
              
                  </script>